# How do I stop my php login from outputing results in content area?

Tags: php, html, forms, authentication, include

I have an in-progress website, the design work is done, but im working on making the website dynamic. I have a section on the site with a login section that includes a login form. I have my login script working, but when a user is logged in the login form stays on the website and the members section appears where my content is. Here is an example of the site design/config:

Index.php
--file includes sections of design exp: include(header, navigation, content, sidebar, footer)

```
<body>
<?php include("header.php");?>
<?php include("navigation.php");?>
<?php include("content.php");?>
<?php include("sidebar.php");?>
<?php include("footer.php");?>
</body>
```

Content.php
--contains php include and navigation snippet to output links, `index.php?od=file`

```
<?php
if ($_REQUEST["od"]=="home") include("incs/news.html");
elseif ($_REQUEST["od"]=="portfolio") include("incs/portfolio.html");
elseif ($_REQUEST["od"]=="tutorials") include("incs/tutorials.html");
elseif ($_REQUEST["od"]=="resources") include("incs/resources.html");
elseif ($_REQUEST["od"]=="services") include("incs/services.php");
elseif ($_REQUEST["od"]=="contact") include("incs/contactus.html");
elseif ($_REQUEST["od"]=="webhosting") include("incs/webhosting.html");
elseif ($_REQUEST["od"]=="webdesign") include("incs/webdesign.html");
elseif ($_REQUEST["od"]=="webdevelopment") include("incs/webdevelopment.html");
elseif ($_REQUEST["od"]=="repairs") include("incs/repairs.html");
elseif ($_REQUEST["od"]=="login") include("login/login-exec.php");
elseif ($_REQUEST["od"]=="logfail") include("login/login-failed.php");
elseif ($_REQUEST["od"]=="register") include("login/register-form.php");
elseif ($_REQUEST["od"]=="registerex") include("login/register-exec.php");
elseif ($_REQUEST["od"]=="regsuccess") include("login/register-success.php");
elseif ($_REQUEST["od"]=="denied") include("login/access-denied.php");
elseif ($_REQUEST["od"]=="account") include("login/member-index.php");
elseif ($_REQUEST["od"]=="profile") include("login/member-profile.php");
elseif ($_REQUEST["od"]=="logout") include("login/logout.php");
else include("incs/news.html");
?>
```

sidebar.php
--contains html forms for logging in

```
<form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" method="post" action="login/login-exec.php">
                        <p align="left" class="description"><label for="username"><b>Username:</b></label></p>
                        <p align="left"><input name="username" type="text" id="username" size="40" maxlength="40" /></p>

                        <p align="left" class="description"><label for="password"><b>Password:</b></label></p>
                        <p align="left"><input name="password" type="password" size="40" maxlength="100" id="password" /></p>

                        <p align="right"><input name="login" type="submit" value="Log In" id="submit" /></p>

                        <h6 align="left">&raquo; <a href="./index.php?od=register"><font color="#565656">Not Registered?</font></a></h6>
                        <h6 align="left">&raquo; <a href="./index.php?od=fgtpsswd"><font color="#565656">Forgot Password?</font></a></h6>
                        <input type="hidden" name="ref" value="{REF}" />
                    </form>
```

/login/login-exec.php

```
    if($result) {
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
        //Login Successful
        session_regenerate_id();
        $account = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        $_SESSION['SESS_ACCOUNT_ID'] = $account['id'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] = $account['firstname'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME'] = $account['lastname'];
        session_write_close();
        header("location: ../index.php?od=account");
        exit();
    }else {
        //Login failed
        header("location: /index.php?od=logfail");
        exit();
    }
```

The login scripts are located in a folder called /login/, I would like for my form to switch to a members panel of links to secured section. I'm guessing an php if and elseif statement is necessary but not sure. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: "Anyone got any ideas?" Not without seeing some code...

Comment: You've left out the most important script: login-exec.php. It produces the page that you go to when you login.

Comment: If the login form sets a session variable, sidebar.php can check the variable and replace the login form with a logout button. I don't understand what you mean by "the members section appears where my content is"

Comment: I updated with login-exec.php code that initiates a logged in and header statement. And I have a content section where all my main pages are displayed. When I loggin from the form to the right of the content, my members panel is displayed where my content should be, id rather it be were the form was to the right of the content, and all my main content would appear along side the members panel.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. (sidebar.php)

```
<? if($_SESSION['SESS_ACCOUNT_ID'] == ''): ?>    
<form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" method="post" action="login/login-exec.php">
    <p align="left" class="description"><label for="username"><b>Username:</b></label></p>
    <p align="left"><input name="username" type="text" id="username" size="40" maxlength="40" /></p>
    <p align="left" class="description"><label for="password"><b>Password:</b></label></p>
    <p align="left"><input name="password" type="password" size="40" maxlength="100" id="password" /></p>
    <p align="right"><input name="login" type="submit" value="Log In" id="submit" /></p>
    <h6 align="left">&raquo; <a href="./index.php?od=register"><font color="#565656">Not Registered?</font></a></h6>
    <h6 align="left">&raquo; <a href="./index.php?od=fgtpsswd"><font color="#565656">Forgot Password?</font></a></h6>
    <input type="hidden" name="ref" value="{REF}" />
</form>
<? endif; ?>
```

Comment: Didnt do anything for me, still see the results populate in my content section.

Comment: Try the new update and let me know. If that doesnt work, then please add <? echo $_SESSION['SESS_ACCOUNT_ID']; ?> to sidebar.php, make sure your logged out and see what it gives you.

Comment: when i login it directs me to the members page in my content area and the form in the login section, but after i login if i click register the form dissapears and the account id is all that displays.

Comment: So when your logged in, the html login form goes away and the only thing displayed is your account id? And if you logout, then the form is present?

Comment: no only when i click register does the form change to my account id, but that is only if im logged in and click register

Comment: The login form your trying to get rid of. In sidebar.php, what happends to that?

Comment: it stayed on the main page until i clicked register and was redirected to the register page at which point it was replaced with my account id

Comment: So the login form is only hidden on the register page but remains visible on all other pages?

Comment: And when you added the echo to the sidebar.php, what does it say when your NOT logged in on any page?

Comment: i have that added and it doesnt echo anything

Comment: same exact thing except no account id, theres nothing, but the member page still populates in my content field, how to i get it to appear in the same section the form was in.

Comment: i would also like to note that i dont want to be able to go to the register page if im logged in seeing as i already have an account lol

Comment: Sorry. I am lost, you keep talking about pages and a register page, yet, isnt the idea here to get rid of a form in a sidebar? I am confused.